# On what principle the Bose's way of counting is based?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In Bose's attempt to rederive Planck's law of radiation based on purely quantum postulates, he carried out the following calculation $$ \frac{A^{s}!}{P_{0}^{s}!P_{1}^{s}!...}$$

Where $A^{s}$ is the total number of cells in the 6D phase space available for photons whose frequency is between $\nu^{s}$ and $\nu^{s}+d\nu^{s}$ and $P_{i}^{s}$ is the number of cells of the $A^{s}$ cells containing i number of photons, my question is under what category  the above formula lies, is it the total number of ways of partitioning the set $A^{s}$ into $P_{i}^{s}$'s subsets?

Comment: This equivalent to multinomial theorem , Let $A^s$ be the the number of cells in 6D phase space then We actually need the coefficient of  $\prod_{i=1}^k a_{i} ^{P^{s}_{i}}$ $(a_1+a_2+...+a_n)^{A^s}$ , which is what you have written in factorials.